# How to add a button to image gallery in Elementor

Tags: elementor

Need to add a button below every image in Elementor gallery lightbox.
This button must be a mailto: with name of the image in subject line.
This is an inquiry button for that image.

I have tried to add some css, but i'm not familiar with css.

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/be6et.jpg ”example”

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new button can't be achieved through CSS. You're gonna have to edit the widget and add a new field, that is done with PHP.

Comment: Any alternative? Plugin or something to show gallery in lightbox and this button to make an enquiry?

Comment: There are lots of plugins that add new widgets to Elementor. I'm not familiar with one that has this particular functionality but if you search for Elementor Gallery Widgets you may find one that suits your needs.

Comment: I searched but couldn't find anything that could add a button over the photos in the photo gallery.

Comment: What is the widget that you are currently using that works the most like what you need (except for the button)?

Comment: Gallery from Elementor PRO